# How can I run 3 4K monitors on my 2015 MBP

Tags: display

I just seen a video of a guy on YouTube running 6 4K monitors natively on his MBP but it didn't go into details as far as cabling/hub setup. How could I run just 3 4K at 60hz? I am confused as to the best way to get 2 thunderbolt into 3 DisplayPort. I haven't picked out a specific monitor yet but they will be DisplayPort monitors.

I have a 2015 MBP with the AMD graphics card.

I am not interested in eGPU options.

Comment: Dang, I was really hoping to get a great answer for this. :(

Answer (score 3):

The way you connect more than 2 **external** displays to a MacBook (or any laptop for that matter) is to use USB display adapters like the [StarTech USB 3.0 to 4K DisplayPort External Multi Monitor Video Graphics Adapter](http://radnex.us/startech-usb-displayport-4K)

[image]

Each one of these adapters will function like a separate graphics card allowing you to hook up as many monitors as you have adapters.  So, to get your *six* external monitors, you can have two natively connected to your MacBook Pro and then you will need 4 of these adapters.

***Note:**  It's important to note that this setup is **not** for gaming.  These are not high performance external GPUs.  This is for connecting an additional display.

*Additionally, there are limitation with with OS X that will cause performance problems.  Some are limitations due to Apple, and others are limitations due to the driver.  Always check the [Release Notes](https://sgcdn.startech.com/005329/media/sets/DisplayLink_Drivers/Mac-release-notes.txt) prior to purchase and/or installation.*

If you're on a 2013 or later Mac Pro, you can natively connect 3 monitors without the need for special adapters.  However, there is a caveat with the Thunderbolt 0 bus and HDMI port.

See [How do I connect a 3rd 4K monitor to my 2013 Mac Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298476/how-do-i-connect-a-3rd-4k-monitor-to-my-2013-mac-pro?noredirect=1#298480)

Comment: Thanks for the post but those only seem to support 30Hz.

Comment: Try this one....[Plugable USB 3.0 to HDMI 4K UHD](http://amzn.to/29H2q4o).  Problem is, it's not DP.  Can it be HDMI?  This one is 60Hz and supports OS X

Comment: that is only HDMI 1.4 which does not support 4k at 60hz. Which is because HDMI 2.0 spec calls for 18Gbps where USB 3.0 only has 5Gbps. It might be possible to find a monitor that supports 4k@60hz through two HDMI cables and in that case this could possible be viable but undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect multiple displays or other thunderbolt devices, via the thunderbolt connection.
Take a look at [DisplayPort daisy chaining](http://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/), available from v1.2

Comment: That won't work for 60hz. The spec only allows bandwidth for one at 60hz.

Comment: Plus finding displays with MST support is difficult. :/

Comment: Do the USB adapters work good?