# 3 monitors on a Mac Mini (Mid 2012)

Tags: display, mac-mini, thunderbolt-display

I would like to have three screens connected to my Mac Mini, so far I have one screen connected via HDMI and one screen connected via thunderbolt. The only ports I have left are USB and firewire, would there be any way for me to connect a third monitor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/triple-display-new-mac-mini-2012.1476646/

Comment: This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246427/119271), though for MacBook Pros, provides a solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the 3rd monitor you'll need an HDMI to USB converter but make sure that the converter is Mac compatible, if it isn't I'm not 100% sure but you may be able to find a software to make it mac compatible with the type of converter like I did.