# Mac Mini with x3 Apple Displays/Monitors. Adapters, cables and configuration puzzle

Tags: display, mac-mini, thunderbolt, hdmi, dvi

Anybody successfully attached (or know how to attach) x2 Apple 30" Cinema displays (Male DVI) and x1 Apple 24" Display (Male Mini DisplayPort) to a Mac Mini 2012 (which has the following connections available: x1 HDMI, x1 Mini DisplayPort, x4 USB, x1 Firewire800), with minimum 1920 resolution on all monitors?

I have successfully connected the two 30" Apple Cinema displays using Mini DisplayPort to Dual Link DVI Adapter and HDMI to DVI but the latter is capped at 1080 resolution (cause its not dual link) and from extensive google/amazon searches the only option for the 24" display would be Mini DisplayPort to USB adapter (but the products/adapters I saw have the connections the wrong way round i.e I need a female Mini DisplayPort to receive the 24" monitors cable and a male USB which would then connect to the back of the Mac Mini.

Also looked at hubs which would be ideal if I could connect x2 30" Cinema displays DVI cables into a dual link (for maximum resolution), dual female HDMI which adapted into a single HDMI, which then connected to the back of the Mac Mini, leaving the Mini DisplayPort free to connect the 24" Display. This solution seems ideal but all I could find were HDMI to Mini DisplayPort (no good cause then no free port for the 24" Monitor as described above) or HDMI hubs that didn't suggest they would provide 1920 or above resolutions.

Anyone configured the above successfully or able to venture a solution?

Comment: You can't make video connections appear out of no where, you have to have the processors available to support it.  Your Mac mini supports two, to add a third, your need another graphics adapter (isn't any different on PCs).  See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246427/119271

Comment: @Allan Thank you for providing clarity with your explanation. Of course, now that makes sense. Will check the link.