# 2017 Macbook pro 13 inch 3 monitors help

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

I have done quite a bit of searching and haven't found a solution to my issue. I have a 2017 macbook pro 13 inch with touchbar. I want to be able to use 3 monitors 1080p via apple usb c digital av hub so usb to hdmi for all 3 monitors plugged each into their own port. I can only get two to work including in clamshell mode. Is there a way to get this to work while using laptop as intended or would I have to use bootcamp or something? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [13" 2017 MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP754?locale=en_US) only supports up to two external monitors:

> **Video Support**
>
> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display
>   at millions of colors and:
>
> - One display with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
> - Up to two displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at millions of colors
> - Up to two displays with 3840-by-2160 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors

If you want to get a third display going, you will need a [USB to DVI/HDMI/VGA adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246427/119271).

Comment: Great thanks! I will give that a shot. I do have a usb to vga that I tried but the only thing that happened was it was showing as a removable disk and inside was a .exe file which obviously would not work. I'm assuming that it was only for PC as I wasn't able to find any drivers online.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options that I am aware of to get three displays working on a Macbook Pro 2017 13 inch with 4 USB-C connectors (supports two external screens natively plus the internal screen).

option 1 - Use displaylink technology to connect three screens - I haven't tested this today but it looks like a valid solution, a DELL D6000 looks like it would work.

option 2 - buy a BENQ screen with displayport out example PD2700U. The BENQ manual says you need to have a second BENQ screen to daisychain to a second screen but I have this working using a usb-c to (not mini) displayport to the BENQ monitor displayport, then a daisy chain using the displayport out port to a second monitor, which in my case is a Philips PHL 276E8V. The third monitor is plugged into a mac USB-C port.

1. BENQ PD2700U - 3840 x 2160 30 Hz (plugged into Mac USB-C to BENQ displayport
2. Philips 276E8V - 3840 x 2160 30 Hz (Daisy chained to BENQ using DP to DP)
3. Philips 276E8V - 3840 x 2160 60 Hz (Plugged into Mac USB-C to HDMI input)

Does the job nicely.